# Java reverse clipping region?

Tags: java, graphics, clipping

Hi I'm making a flash light for a game. I make the flashlight using Arc2D and basically clip part of the map so that only that part shows up, but I also want part of the map to so up too.

Is there anyway to reverse my clipped region and get the region not being clipped?
[image]

How do I get the black region?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Area#subtract`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#subtract-java.awt.geom.Area-) method to obtain the desired area:

```
Rectangle2D screen = 
    new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,screenWidth, screenHeight);
Area result = new Area(screen);
Area clippingArea = new Area(yourArcClipShape);
result.subtract(clippingArea);
```

The `result` will then be the shape of the full screen, *except* for your original "arc" clipping shape - that is, the black area in the image.

Related answers, showing some light effects and image compositing:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21778759/3182664
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23971327/3182664